# Python Matplotlib equivalent of get(gca,'Children') matlab statement

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

Hello I need the equivalent instruction of this matlab statement:

```
h=get(gca,'Children');
```

for matplotlib

Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: What does this command do in matlab?

Comment: it returns all the objects in graphic current axis

Answer (score 2):

To get all objects from the current axes, you can use [`get_children`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children)

```
h = plt.gca().get_children()
```

Comment: after that i get h , i have to execute the following matlab statement in python: `(strcmp(get(h(jh),'Type'),'quiver')` . I'm not able to find attribute type